# How to minmax normalize data and build as json in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a simple table tracking values over time for different users as a postgres database that looks like this:

| user_id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2021-01-01' | 1 |
| 1 | '2021-01-02' | 2 |
| 1 | '2021-01-03' | 3 |
| 2 | '2021-01-01' | 1 |
| 2 | '2021-01-02' | 2 |
| 2 | '2021-01-03' | 3 |

And I want to return this data as an array of json objects so I do something like this...

```
select
  user_id,
  coalesce(
    json_agg(
      'date', date,
      'value', value
    ),
    '[]'
  ) as values
from user_table
group by user_id
```

But let's say that I also wanted to return another column of json objects called `values_normalized` where it's the same thing except the values are minmax normalized between 0 and 1.

My assumption is that I could do something like this -

```
select
  user_id,
  coalesce(
    json_agg(
      'date', date,
      'value', ((values - min(values) over ())::float / (max(values) over () - min(values) over ())::float)
    ),
    '[]'
  ) as values
from user_table
group by user_id
```

But this is giving me an error "aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls"

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Use a subquery to calculate the values, then construct the JSON.

Comment: @GordonLinoff didn't want to admit that this was the only way lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple subquery that is easy:

```
SELECT user_id,
       coalesce(
          json_agg(
             'date', date,
             'value', (value - minvalue)::float /
                      (maxvalue - minvalue)::float
          ),
          '[]'
       ) AS values
FROM (SELECT user_id, date, value
             min(value) OVER () AS minvalue,
             max(value) OVER () AS maxvalue,
      FROM user_table) AS subq
GROUP BY user_id;
```